# How to check if record exists before reading in Dapper ORM

Tags: dapper

Can anyone please suggest how to check if there are any records in the resultset using Dapper ORM.

```
Customer objCustomer = null;
using (SqlMapper.GridReader multiResult = new DapperRepository().QueryMultiple(sql, new { id = id }))
{
    objCustomer = multiResult.Read<Customer>().Single(); //null exception
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write this:

```
objCustomer = multiResult.Read<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(); //return null if not exists without error
```

then you can check:

```
objCustomer != null
```

Hope this helps.